# Was F5 function key assigned to widgets view in old OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dashboard-widget

I've a customer claiming that the default function for F5 key on his mac is to launch the widgets screen.

Is this true? Can be an old apple keyboard or an old OS X such as Snow Leopard with this default setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was always F4, as far as I can recall.

My 08 keyboard has it printed on the key itself - same layout as this picture

[image]

Prior to the introduction of the aluminium keyboard in 2007, there were no icons printed on the keys, so it would be hard to say for certain - but as Snow Leopard was 2009, it would be unlikely it would be anywhere other than where the printed key indicates on anything later than Leopard, 10.5, which would have been roughly coincidental to the introduction of that keyboard design.

[The Evolution Of Apple Design Between 1977-2008](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/01/the-evolution-of-apple-design-between-1977-2008/) would appear to support that.

Comment: I forgot my keyboard even had these keys ha!

Answer (score 0):

The F4 key was assigned to launching the Widgets screen on Leopard/Snow Leopard era keyboards, it has since been assigned to Launchpad. As it's the fifth key along your customer could possibly be confusing it for F5...

Comment: I never use the 'printed keys' myself, have had it switched back to standard F-Keys since new - but are you sure it's Launchpad on F4? I get nothing at all on F5 & F6, the others still do what's printed on them. Has the printed icon & matching function been changed on newer machines?

Comment: @Tetsujin F5 & F6 are for keyboard backlit.

Comment: AH, OK - I don't have a backlit keyboard; old Mac Pro here; but my main point was, has F4's function changed on newer machines or is it still Widgets, as on my 08 keyboard?

Comment: This 2012 MacBook Pro 13" I'm using has F4 marked for Launchpad, as do both the Bluetooth and wired keyboards on nearby iMacs. My 2011 MBP 15" has F4 marked for Widgets.

Comment: If the F4 key is marked for Widgets that's what it will do, the same goes for keys marked for launchpad. I can't answer for older "Pro" keyboards without specif marked functions as I don't have one to hand here at work. Can check later at home if it's still an issue.